# Marker click listener jsf2leaf

Tags: javascript, leaflet, cartography

I am using jsf2leaf library to add a map to a web application using primefaces. The map and the markers(popup message when clicked) are displayed correctly, however I want to display a **primefaces dialog** when a marker is clicked instead of the popup message.

any idea of how can I add a click listener to the markers!?